# How can I safely stop postfix being picky about group permissions of sqlite database?

Tags: postfix, permissions, sqlite

### Background

I set up an example postfix server using sqlite to store the aliases and mailbox details, (so that they could be updated live and have a single source of truth being the database.)

I have the parts of postfix running chroot where possible for security, so the database (mail.sqlite) is in /var/lib/postfix/
(That all works.)

### The required functionality

I wrote a web front end to let users add new email addresses. The web front end is running as www-data.

I added www-data to the postfix group so that `chmod g+rw /var/lib/postfix/mail.sqlite /var/lib/postfix/` would enable the web front end to update the database.

Email is flowing in and out. The web front end can Create Remote Update Delete aliases. I restart postfix and check the logs:

```sh
postfix/postfix-script[26524]: warning: group or other writable: /var/lib/postfix/.
postfix/postfix-script[26525]: warning: group or other writable: /var/lib/postfix/./mail.sqlite
```

If I `chmod g-w /var/lib/postfix/mail.sqlite` that makes postfix happy, but removed the ability for my web front end to add new aliases.

I could have a cron script to replace /var/lib/postfix/mail.sqlite with an authoritative /var/www/admin/app/mail.sqlite, but that smells like race condition,
or at least is inelegant.

(I wonder why postfix is referring to the database as "/var/lib/postfix/./mail.sqlite" when the config is `dbpath = /var/lib/postfix/mail.sqlite`?)

## The question

How can I give my cgi web front end write access to postfix's database, without running it *as* postfix **and** while keeping postfix happy? (I think that I have to solve this before I add in SELinux policies.)

## Edit:

I had main.cf with

```
virtual_mailbox_maps = sqlite:/etc/postfix/sqlite_mailbox.cf
virtual_alias_maps = sqlite:/etc/postfix/sqlite_alias.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = sqlite:/etc/postfix/sqlite_domains.cf
```

and have tried proxymap:

```
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:sqlite:/etc/postfix/sqlite_mailbox.cf
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:sqlite:/etc/postfix/sqlite_alias.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:sqlite:/etc/postfix/sqlite_domains.cf
```

Both seem to work equally well for email processing, but after restarting postfix, both still log:

```
postfix/postfix-script[957]: warning: group or other writable: /var/lib/postfix/.             
postfix/postfix-script[958]: warning: group or other writable: /var/lib/postfix/./mail.sqlite
```

Comment: Why do you stick with SQLite? Is there any reasoning behind this? MariaDB (MySQL) is cheap and easy way to do the same thing without worrying about file permissions.

Comment: I love MariaDB but this environment is limited and installing a full database is overkill for a simple key:value lookup.

Comment: Then have you tried to use a postfix [proxymap](http://www.postfix.org/proxymap.8.html) service?

Comment: I had not tried proxymap. It looks like that is the best solution. I've tried it but postfix is still warning about group permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of this error is from the script "postfix-script" at this point:

```
find $queue_directory/. $queue_directory/pid \
    -prune \( -perm -020 -o -perm -002 \) \
    -exec $WARN group or other writable: {} \;
..
find $todo \( -perm -020 -o -perm -002 \) \
    -exec $WARN group or other writable: {} \;
..
find $data_directory/. \( -perm -020 -o -perm -002 \) \
    -exec $WARN group or other writable: {} \;
..
```

`$todo` is effectively `config_directory`, `shlib_directory`, `daemon_directory` and `meta_directory` as a list.

You can run the `postconf` command to work out what those variables are.

```
$ postconf queue_directory config_directory daemon_directory meta_directory shlib_directory data_directory
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
meta_directory = /etc/postfix
shlib_directory = /usr/lib64/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
```

This would seem to suggest, if you keep the the actual sqlite databases *outside* of those directories, postfix-script will be unawares to check them.

So you could just create something new shared by the web server and the mail server, say - `/srv/maildb/` setup the ownerships as per your preferences and get around it like that.

Oh, I would point out you'd probably want to alter your chroot environment to support loading the data in. You could potentially use a hard link but that feels like a hack.